# Probability of 6 or more choosing same course

Tags: probability

> If 15 students have to choose 4 courses from 15, what is the
>   probability of 6 or more students selecting the same course.

Thanks to Cato in the comments below, this is what I have been able to formulate so far.

$n\,(number\,of\,students) = 15$

$p\,(probability\,of\,a\,course\,being\,selected\,by\,a\,student) 
        = \frac{no.\,of\,choice}{no.\,of\,courses\,offered}
        = \frac{4}{15}$

$q = 1-p = \frac{11}{15}$

Let X be the random variable denoting the number of students enrolled in a course,

Using Binomial Distribution where,
$$P(X = r) = {n \choose r}*p^r*q^{(n-r)}$$

$P(X >= 6) = P(X = 6) + P(X = 7) + P(X = 8) + ... + P(X = 15) 
              \simeq 0.1875$

So there is only about 18.75% probability that any course will be selected by 6 or more students.

> Using Normal approximation of binomial:

$\mu = n * p = 4$

$\sigma = \sqrt{n*p*q} \simeq 1.713$

$P(X > 6) = P(Z > \frac{6-4}{1.713}) \simeq 0.121$

Using Normal approximation, the probability is reduced to about 12%.

Comment: So I'm not sure how to solve this problem, but I'd start simple. How many ways can the students choose the courses? That would be $\binom{15}{4}^5$

Comment: @SakethMalyala Why did you use the power of 5 to 15 choose 4 ? Anyways this is the total combination of 4 courses a student can choose from 15 courses. However, what I want to know is that in a class of 15 students, what is the probability that 6 or more students choose the same course. This is a real life scenario that we are dealing right now.

Comment: is it one particular course, or just that 6+ students are enrolled on any course.  Since you've now provided further info as to your thoughts and context - I'd hope that they will take this Q off hold

Comment: you might be able to esitmate it with poisson distribution - there are 60 choosings of courses, the number of choosings of each course could be modelled as poisson with parameter 4 - the chances that none of them get 6 seems quite low - I know this is only provides an estimate, not an exact value

Comment: Actually for any course to be conducted, we need at least 6 students enrolled. So if X is a random variable that represents the number of students enrolled in any course, what is P(X >= 6) ?

Comment: if there's a course, 'course A' for example, then there seems to be an 81% chance that it will have less than 6 students choosing it.  Seems to me that on average each course will get 4 people choosing it, with a standard deviation of a bit less than 2, so many of your courses will not get filled

Comment: i don't know how to calculate it exactly, I could do a computer simulation, it would tell you the relative frequencies of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6  etc courses being able to start.

Comment: You didn't apply the continuity correction for your normal approximation. You need $P(Z>\tfrac{6-4-0.5}{1.713})$.